# Python/Django: import weirdness

Tags: python, django, python-import

I've the following project setup

```
....
├── lira
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── ajax.py
│   ├── authentication.py
│   ├── context_processors.py
│   ├── fencoder
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── encoder.py
│   │   ├── ffmpeg_commands.py
│   │   ├── frames.py
│   │   ├── utils.py
│   │   └── video.py
│   ├── models.py
....
```

And when I try to import `from lira.fencoder import encoder` I get an error `ImportError: cannot import name encoder`.

What is wrong with the above project setup though this morning it was the same and it worked?

Sultan

Comment: Did you mean `from lira.fencoder import *`? What is the content of `lira/fencoder/__init__.py`?

Comment: I meant ANY equal encoder,frames etc. the only contents of `lira/fencoder/__init__.py` is the line of `__author__="sultan"`

Comment: if it was working this morning and no more now, what did you change ? On the other hand, it could be a cyclic import that is failing.

Comment: I didn't change anything in the structure of directories but worked a lot of on different files within. Ahh byt the way I've imports of encoder from models and the imports of models from encoder. How to avoid this stuff with cyclic imports?

Comment: @Cédric Julien this was all about cyclic imports, so far I removed imports from encoder and it worked fine, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to debug import problems, sometimes a simple launch of

```
python -v -m path/to/python/module/to_start
```

will help you, it will show you all the imports done by the python interpreter and help detect cyclic imports.